# What's the best way to transfer a GIT-SVN debug->feature branch to trunk?

Tags: git, git-svn

I've got a trunk setup where all my production code goes.

Then I have a `debug` branch (parent is `trunk`) which I add debugging code such as logging, var dumps, etc... this should never be in production. This branch rarely changes.

Lastly I have a `feature` branch (parent is `debug`) where I do all my coding with the benefits of debugging. There are constant commits to this branch.

I just want to know if there is an easier way to move my `feature` code to the `trunk`. This is what I currently do:

1. Commit all changes to my `feature` branch
2. Switch to `master` and `git svn rebase` changes from other devs.
3. `rebase` my `feature` branch onto the `master` branch (`git rebase --onto master debug feature`)
4. `merge` feature to `master`
5. `git svn dcommit` changes to other devs
6. `rebase` `debug` to `master` (`git rebase master debug`)
7. delete `feature` branch
8. create a new `feature` from the `debug` branch.

Comment: Maybe I should make it a new question but is it really a good practice to put debugging code in its own branch rather than something you can turn on/off at runtime?

Comment: Personally I don't want to run the risk of forgetting to add #ifdebug statements to my code and ending up sending stuff out into production. I also played around with the notion of patches. Creating a debug patch that I would apply during development and un-patch it when it was ready for release, but that would cause conflicts and trying to keep the patch up to date was a pain.

Comment: @Damien: Personally, I'm with you. I think the more sane solution is to allow enabling/disabling of debug stuff at runtime (or at the *very* least, at compile time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that your work-flow is pretty optimal. I would consider cherry-picking to be an overkill (but it depends on the number of commits).

What you could do is squash all the commits into one and cherry-pick/rebase just this one.

And btw, why just don't write a simple script if it is something you do all the time? Git is a bit low level tool, so writing extra scripts to help with repetitive tasks is a very good idea.

Comment: Yeah the cherry-pick seems like like a lot of work. Besides when I do a merge to trunk I do a --squash so SVN sees the final commit as a single commit. And I do have a bash script to this whole thing, just didn't know if there was an easier way because I have "pauses" at each step to check that nothing went wrong, works fine just have to watch it all the time.

Comment: @JD just check the git return value and if something fails, simply run bash. That will give you an interactive prompt to fix stuff and when you exit the prompt, the process will continue.

Comment: Not a bad idea, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

If you used svn directly, your workflow would be a lot simpler.

With the [--reintegrate feature of subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchemerge.basicmerging.stayinsync)  it is easy to maintain your trunk and debug branch in sync. To merge your feature branch, you'd merge all the modifications of the feature branch in the trunk. The commands would be something like:

To merge the trunk to debug:

```
cd debug_branch_workcopy
svn merge --reintegrate http://server/project/trunk .
svn commit
```

To merge the feature branch to to trunk:

```
svn log --stop-on-copy http://server/project/branches/feature123 #see the last revision listed
cd trunk_workcopy
svn merge -r{revision_above}:HEAD http://server/project/branches/feature123 .
svn commit
```

You can run the last merge command multiple times if you change the branch after the merge. Subversion will remember the already merged revisions and won't try to do them twice. If you are in Windows, the free TortoiseSVN will give you a nice merge interface.

BTW, I'd try not to have a separate branch just with debugging features. It is too easy to make a manual error and send debug code to your production trunk. I'd use something more dynamic to not run the debug code while in production.

Comment: Yup ran into the same problem of sending debug code to prod with SVN, that's one of the reasons I switch to git. I can just tell it to copy after the debug commit to the HEAD without having to keep track of revision numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you'd like to have your debug features only in your (pretty static) debug branch, but not in your master branch. Try this:

Do a "fake merge" of debug into master

```
git checkout master
git merge --no-commit debug
git checkout master .        # undo all changes, get the files from master again
git add .                    # stage all files
git commit
```

This way, debug will be merged into master, but none of your files in master will have changed.

Now you can simply create your feature branches on top of debug, and merge them into master when you're done. Git now knows that the debug features are stripped from master:

```
git checkout debug
git checkout -b new_feature  # create a new feature branch
# hack, hack, hack
git commit
git checkout master          # All works fine...
git merge new_feature        # ...so merge into master. Debug code will be stripped here
```

You can fast-forward the debug branch on new_feature and delete the new_feature branch after this.

Note that whenever you change the debug branch, you have to redo the fake merge procedure.

Comment: the debug branch is working, it's moving the changes from the feature branch that's a pain. I have a debug branch forked from the trunk and then a feature branch forked from the debug branch. Then I move the feature code using the commands above, just trying to see if there was an easier way.

Comment: I've added an example of how to merge feature code into master. Is it clearer now?

Comment: +1, this is a good technique to know about. However, your debug code will be lost as soon as you try to merge new features in from `master`. So, after merging new features into `debug`, cherry-pick your debug commits back into `debug` (i.e. Fewer cherry picks this way). ALSO: When doing a 'Fake Merge', please make sure the mergecommit message reflects this fact, for the sanity of your teammates.

Answer (score 0):

We have a separate branch for each feature or bug fix we do.  These can then be merged back to trunk when they have been sufficiently tested.

Branches can be updated if they become a bit old.

We tend to release minor changes directly to trunk, but for more major changes we gather them into a release candidate branch into which we merge all the relevant branches containing changes to go live.  This new branch can be deployed and tested to see if combining changes breaks anything, before it is finally merged back to trunk and goes into production.

This method creates a lot of branches, but since we name these related to our issue tracking system they are easy to keep track of. It is nice an easy to either include or exclude any changes to a release.

Hope that helps

Comment: My question was more GIT specific and I like you incorporate most of this into my current work-flow, but for simplicity I described a basic example.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is git-cherry-pick. This allows you to apply commits from feature on master without doing the rebase dance you describe.

Since you're going to delete the feature branch anyway you don't need to see an explicit merge I presume.

Answer (score 0):

Your workflow is complicated because what you are trying to do is complicated. No VCS that I know of lets you easily maintain some changes that should never be merged. It says a lot about the power of git that your workflow is not harder than it is.

I assume your language has some sort of conditional compilation mechanism (`#IFDEF` preprocessor directives, etc). If you wrap your debugging code in these instead you'll experience much less friction.

Comment: I am doing web development with PHP, so the #ifdef approach would work, just going to have to talk to my boss and see if that will fly.